# Not Adding Record with "Space"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using direct url to a record in my database, but my problem was, when the records contains " " or "space" it didn't save. for example:

> name = "Lebron"  this is working.
>
> name = "Lebron James"

this will not work because of the space between first and last name.  Did anyone already encountered this type of error?

Comment: "It didn't save" - usually if you tell software to store information but somehow it is unable to do so, you get an `Exception` or other means of feedback. Or did you mean "it saved something, but not what I expected it to save"?

Comment: it totally not saving every record. And there is no error or exception that has been cathed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) your URL.

E.g

```
string url = "http://myserver/mypage/?name=Lebron James";
url = HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you need to encode your URL.

Answer (score 1):

That space needs to be turned into %20